# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fobjc-link-runtime'

Tags: xcode, gcc, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build a tensorflow tool with bazel on OSX with this command:

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph
```

output of gcc -v:

> gcc version 4.9.4 (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.4_1)

bazel version

> 0.11.1

Xcode version:

> Xcode 9.2

However, i am getting the error:

```
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_macuser/521cd0aef0e1f687906b0f761e1e0f08/external/protobuf_archive/BUILD:259:1: 
 Linking of rule '@protobuf_archive//:js_embed' failed (Exit 1): cc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing command 
  (cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_macuser/521cd0aef0e1f687906b0f761e1e0f08/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    APPLE_SDK_PLATFORM='' \
    APPLE_SDK_VERSION_OVERRIDE='' \
PATH=/anaconda/bin:/Users/macuser/anaconda2/bin:/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/bin:
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/macuser/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin \
    XCODE_VERSION_OVERRIDE=9.2.0 \
  external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh -fobjc-link-runtime -Wl,-S -o `bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf_archive/js_embed bazel-

out/host/bin/external/protobuf_archive/_objs/
js_embed/external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/embed.o -headerpad_max_install_names -lc++ -no-canonical-prefixes)`
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fobjc-link-runtime'
    Target //tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph failed to build
    INFO: Elapsed time: 17.640s, Critical Path: 3.74s
    FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

How can I compile this correctly?

Comment: `-fobjc-link-runtime` is a clang option. `gcc` does not recognize it. Enabled/
disabled in XCode build-settings as shown [here](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/buildsettings.html#clang_link_objc_runtime)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have `CC` environment variable set somewhere? Bazel tries to be smart and detect which toolchain works best for the user, and In your case it looks like it detected toolchain that works for both C++ and ObjC, but then used gcc with that toolchain. That is weird and potentially a reason to report an issue to bazel.

Can you make sure you're using latest bazel and tensorflow, run `bazel clean --expunge`, make sure there is no `CC` environment variable set (or if you want to use gcc set `BAZEL_USE_CPP_ONLY_TOOLCHAIN=1` env var), then run `./configure` in tensorflow, and then build?

Comment: I saw this error with Bazel as well and I don't have a `CC` environment variable set. `gcc version 8.3.0 (MacPorts gcc8 8.3.0_4)`. `bazel 0.28.1`